# Warning: this Gemfile contains multiple primary sources during vagrant-rsync-back plugin Installation

Tags: ruby, rubygems, vagrant, virtual-machine

I installed `vargrant` in my windows 7, my VM box is `CentOS` 6, well vagrant is working fine.But now I want to install `rsync-back` for syncing my VM files to Windows, I am getting few errors.

When I use the command in CMD windows,

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-rsync-back
```

I get the below errors

> Installing the 'vagrant-rsync-back' plugin. This can take a few
>   minutes... Bundler, the underlying system Vagrant uses to install
>   plugins, reported an error. The error is shown below. These errors are
>   usually caused by misconfigured plugin installations or transient
>   network issues. The error from Bundler is:
>
> Could not fetch specs from http://gems.hashicorp.com/
>
> Warning: this Gemfile contains multiple primary sources. Using
>   `source` more than once without a block is a security risk, and may
>   result in installing unexpected gems. T o resolve this warning, use a
>   block to indicate which gems should come from the secondary source. To
>   upgrade this warning to an error, run `bundle config disable_multisou
>   rce true`.

I am pretty new to vagrant, I am unable to solve this issue. Any suggestion where I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

The "multiple primary sources" warning you are seeing is just that: a warning. The error that prevented the installation was the "Could not fetch specs from ..." part you see above the warning.

My guess is just that this gem server was down at the time you tried to install it. In fact, it looks like someone reported a similar issue on the vagrant github repository back in July, and one of the top contributors guessed exactly that: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/5966

Have you tried it again to see if the issue has gone away (the gem server appears to be up for me)?

Comment: Fine , I didnt try I removed the rsync dependency from the vagrant for the time being ! But still if I try I am getting the same error ! :(

Comment: P.S. If you're still curious about the warning, this security vulnerability is the reason Bundler added that: http://bundler.io/blog/2014/08/14/bundler-may-install-gems-from-a-different-source-than-expected-cve-2013-0334.html. It looks like [these lines](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/c84e05fd063f043d71f77aae6d4b01e04d1164ff/lib/vagrant/bundler.rb#L181-L185) are responsible for adding the multiple sources to begin with.

Comment: Are you behind a firewall? If so, this issue may have some ways to help you: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/4748